# ローカルでは動くが、リモート環境で動かない時に考えられる事は何でしょうか？

Tags: python3, ubuntu, django, nginx, twitter-bootstrap

Python,DjangoでWEBシステムの開発をしています。

まずはローカルで動きを確認してその後、リモートのサーバーにデプロイして、もう一度動きを確認しながら開発を行っています。

今回、ローカルでは動くが、リモートでは動かない状況となり、原因が分からず困っております。
解決に向け、方法等についてご教授いただきないでしょうか？

**リモートで動かない状況**

- django-bootstrap-datepicker-plusの動作を加えてから動かなくなった。
- 今回変更を加えた所以外は、しっかり動く

こちらで質問さえてもらった内容で、自分で回答しているように最初はローカルでも、動かなかったのですが、コードを書き換え動くようになりました。
その後、リモート環境にデプロイし、確認してみるとローカルで動かなかった時と同じ動作になってしまします。
質問のサイトページ：[django-bootstrap-datepicker-plusを利用したフォームがうまく機能しない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62157/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus%e3%82%92%e5%88%a9%e7%94%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0%e3%81%8c%e3%81%86%e3%81%be%e3%81%8f%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%97%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

**開発環境（ローカル）**

- Mac: mojave 10.14.6
- Python: 3.7.5
- Django: 2.2.2
- django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus: 3.0.5

**開発環境（リモート）**

- Ubuntu: 19.10
- Python: 3.7.5
- Django: 2.2.2
- django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus: 3.0.5
- nginx:1.16.1
- gunicorn:20.0.4

**デプロイ後に行っている事**

- Ubuntuサーバーの再起動
- nginxの再起動
- gunicornの再起動
- スーパーリロード

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リモート環境でもコード通りに動くようになりました。

原因は、デプロイ後に
`collectstatic`コマンドをしていなかった事です。django-bootstrap-datepicker-plusはCSS関係と大きく関係しているので必要でした。